# Installing two applications that depend on different versions of Qt

Tags: linux, qt, shared-libraries

I have two applications, A and B. A depends on Qt 5.7, while B depends on 5.9. Both of these are in binary format, and I can't recompile them.

They both expect their relevant Qt version to be in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5`, but of course that file can only point to one version at a time.

Is there a way I can run both of these applications at the same time?

Comment: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: You could also use a tool like `chrpath` to rewrite where the applications look for the libraries. Not as simple as the env var, but in exchange it's persistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ipor hinted at in the comments, I managed to run both applications by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running each application.

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/qt/5.whatever`